# How to draw a precision-recall diagram?

Tags: algorithm, diagram

Precision and Recall are some metrics for evaluation algorithms, and they are defined like this:

```
precision = true_positive / (true_positive + false_positive)

recall = true_positive / (true_positive + false_negative)
```

So, I think for every algorithm we have one number for precision and one number for recall, but we see that there are some diagram for evaluating according to precision and recall, I want to know that how can we draw a diagram with just one point?(one precision and one recall for every algorithm)

Comment: Do you run each algorithms on several sets or only one? Reading your question, I understand you have only one point per algorithm.

Comment: You're talking about obtaining a precision-recall curve rather than a single data-point. The key detail is that most classifiers (and related algorithms) have a tunable threshold parameter. That parameter causes different precision and recall values, which gives you the curve.  The free parameter is different for every algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw a histogram with the precision and recall for each algorithm. But it's still a bit difficult to read because for each algorithm there are two values. But you need to decide what is the most important characteristics: a good recall or a good precision?

Have you considered using a F-measure that tries to combine both measures? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score

**Edit:**

My suggestion was to use a histogram:

[image: Histogram]

But another solution is to plot like this:

[image: Cloud]

Both were done using LibreOffice.

Comment: Many thanks, but I need a diagram with both precision and recall, I mean that one axe in diagram is Precision and the other is recall and the curve is according to them. How can I draw this?

Comment: @soodehp Well, you can use as you said one axis for precision and the other for recall. This way you would have one point per algorithm, like a cloud of points. But I'm confused, if you know exactly what you want, I'm not sure to understand your question... Are you looking for a tool to plot it?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not looking for a tool to plot. In the second plot, there is one point for each algorithm, but I saw some plots that there is a curve for each algorithm. How can I have this curve?

Comment: @soodehp If you want a curve for each algorithm, I guess you need more points. Since the precision and recall depends on your input, you can add more input... For a set of multiple inputs, you'll have multiple points and you can draw a curve. Do you have an example of what you are expecting?